# Vue router lazy loading issue when reloading page

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, code-splitting

So I've been playing with vuejs lazy loading feature. 
This is how my router looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

const MyComponent= () => import('../components/MyComponent');

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/component',
      component: MyComponent,
    }
  ]
});
```

Everything works fine when I get to this route via `router-link` but then when I try to refresh the page nothing happens (it just renders blank page without any errors), and this is how my vue dev tools looks like:

[image]

Comment: And is the URL the same as before refreshing? (`/#/component`, I guess?)

Comment: Yes it is. I simply hit F5 or reload and then nothing happens.